# why do I get a core dump when creating an object?

Tags: c++, oop

I am doing some OOP problems and I was provided this code

```cpp
int main() {
 IntegerArray a(2);//This call the constructor
 a.data[0] = 4; a.data[1] = 2;
 if (true) {
 IntegerArray b = a;
 }
 cout << a.data[0] << endl; // The result is 4
}
```

I add the indentation to the code and created the class which contains two constructors and a destructor

```cpp
class IntegerArray
{
    public:
        int *data;
        IntegerArray()
        {
            data = new int[1];
        }
        IntegerArray(int len)
        {
            data = new int[len];
        }

        ~IntegerArray()
        {
            delete data;
        }
};


int main() 
{
    IntegerArray a(2);//This call the constructor
    
    a.data[0] = 4;
    a.data[1] = 2;
    
    if (true) 
        IntegerArray b = a;
    
    printf("%d\n", a.data[0]);
}
```

The question is why does this code cause a core dump in `IntegerArray b = a` isn't it copying the object `a` into a new object `b`, I guess this is my understanding of Exercise [3](https://erlerobotics.gitbooks.io/erle-robotics-cpp-gitbook/content/memory_management/exercises_memory.html)

This is the program output

```
0
free(): double free detected in tcache 2
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: Search for "C++ rule of three".

Comment: What do you suppose happens in the line `IntegerArray b = a;`, do you have any idea so far?

Comment: @user253751 I am assuming that the object `a` is being copied into `b` hence the `free detected` but i am not sure

Comment: @loaded_dypper -- Look at the duplicate link, and go to the section that says **Managing resources** -- right there is a perfect example of the mistake you are making.

Comment: @loaded_dypper focus on what `~IntegerArray()` does when `data` has been copied to multiple objects.

Comment: `new`/`delete`, `new []`/`delete []`

Comment: @DrewDormann isn't the data copied in `IntegerArray`?

Comment: @loaded_dypper `IntegerArray` contains **a single pointer**.  The pointer is copied.  Both objects have the same pointer.  Both objects try to `delete` the same pointer.  That causes a core dump.  You can learn much more detail about this by [reading the duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three).

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I can't seem to figure out how to make a copy assignment operator, could you please elaborate how to do so

Comment: @loaded_dypper Doesn't the solution at the link you posted show you the way to do this?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie it does but i don't seem to get the full picture

Comment: @loaded_dypper you may have a new [question to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).  Asking many questions in long comment chains will have limited visibility to people who might answer you as well as future visitors with the same questions.

Comment: @loaded_dypper Yes, data is a pointer and so the pointer gets copied. Now both a.data and b.data contain the same address (because it was copied). So what happens when ~IntegerArray runs for b - it destroys the data, right?

Comment: an important thing to know is that a.data isn't the data, just a pointer to the data (== a variable that stores the address of where the data is)

Comment: @loaded_dypper You should also know that if you replaced `int *data;` with `std::vector<int> data;` all of this work will already be written for you.  Your class will _just work_ and won't need a user-defined destructor anymore.

Comment: @DrewDormann this is good to know but i am learning the basics before using other header files

Comment: @loaded_dypper -- It could be said that `std::vector` *is* the "basics", and what you are attempting to do is more advanced.